# Why are homescreen icons bouncing?

Tags: home-screen, 9.0-pie

My wife and I just got new Essential phones running Android 9 (Pie.) On my wife's phone, the docked toolbar icons at the bottom of the homescreen bounce every few seconds, as if they're asking for attention.

She didn't install any weird UI tweak to force this. What is the purpose of the bouncing?

Comment: Likely hinting at "swipe up for app drawer" - do that a few times and it *should* be gone.

Comment: @AndyYan never saw it happen in the past year or two, so perhaps that's what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

I went back into settings, system, gestures, and toggled "swipe up on home button" off then back on.